# Get all unique combinations from array for a given number of elements

Tags: php, algorithm, recursion, combinations, subset-sum

I wanted to have a way to get all combinations for all given numbers with given array length.
In my project the array size usually is 7. So I write a test code like this to see if I can get all needed combinations. The important part is every result array must be unique and maximum array size must be 7.

```
<?php
$numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7];

$arraysize = 7;

$subset = [];
$count = count($numbers);
for ($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++) {
    $subset[] = $numbers[$i];
}

for ($i=0; $i < $count; $i++) {
    for ($j=$i; $j < $count; $j++) {
        $subset[] = $numbers[$i] . $numbers[$j];
    }
}

for ($i=0; $i < $count; $i++) {
    for ($j=$i; $j < $count; $j++) {
        for ($k=$j; $k < $count; $k++) {
            $subset[] = $numbers[$i] . $numbers[$j] . $numbers[$k];
        }
    }
}

for ($i=0; $i < $count; $i++) {
    for ($j=$i; $j < $count; $j++) {
        for ($k=$j; $k < $count; $k++) {
            for ($l=$k; $l < $count; $l++) {
                $subset[] = $numbers[$i] . $numbers[$j] . $numbers[$k] . $numbers[$l];
            }
        }
    }
}

for ($i=0; $i < $count; $i++) {
    for ($j=$i; $j < $count; $j++) {
        for ($k=$j; $k < $count; $k++) {
            for ($l=$k; $l < $count; $l++) {
                for ($m=$l; $m < $count; $m++) {
                    $subset[] = $numbers[$i] . $numbers[$j] . $numbers[$k] . $numbers[$l] . $numbers[$m];
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

for ($i=0; $i < $count; $i++) {
    for ($j=$i; $j < $count; $j++) {
        for ($k=$j; $k < $count; $k++) {
            for ($l=$k; $l < $count; $l++) {
                for ($m=$l; $m < $count; $m++) {
                    for ($n=$m; $n < $count; $n++) {
                        $subset[] = $numbers[$i] . $numbers[$j] . $numbers[$k] . $numbers[$l] . $numbers[$m] . $numbers[$n];
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

for ($i=0; $i < $count; $i++) {
    for ($j=$i; $j < $count; $j++) {
        for ($k=$j; $k < $count; $k++) {
            for ($l=$k; $l < $count; $l++) {
                for ($m=$l; $m < $count; $m++) {
                    for ($n=$m; $n < $count; $n++) {
                        for ($o=$n; $o < $count; $o++) {
                            $subset[] = $numbers[$i] . $numbers[$j] . $numbers[$k] . $numbers[$l] . $numbers[$m] . $numbers[$n] . $numbers[$o];
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

echo "<pre>";
print_r($subset);
echo "</pre>";
?>
```

When I run this code I get the combinations like I wanted (I make the combinations as string to see the results clearly but normally every result item in `$subset` array must be array)
With this code I can get all unique combinations.

But as you can see this code is ugly. I tried to make this a recursive function but I failed. Could anyone point me to right direction to get the exact same results like this? (every item in `$subset` array normally must be an array that contains digits)

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I finally found out a way to add recursive function to create unique combinations from given numbers:

```
$numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7];

function subsetSumRecursive($numbers, $arraySize, $level = 1, $i = 0, $addThis = [])
{
    // If this is the last layer, use a different method to pass the number.
    if ($level == $arraySize) {
        $result = [];
        for (; $i < count($numbers); $i++) {
            $result[] = array_merge($addThis, array($numbers[$i]));
        }
        return $result;
    }

    $result = [];
    $nextLevel = $level + 1;
    for (; $i < count($numbers); $i++) {
        // Add the data given from upper level to current iterated number and pass
        // the new data to a deeper level.
        $newAdd = array_merge($addThis, array($numbers[$i]));
        $temp = subsetSumRecursive($numbers, $arraySize, $nextLevel, $i, $newAdd);
        $result = array_merge($result, $temp);
    }

    return $result;
}

echo "<pre>";
print_r(subsetSumRecursive($numbers, 7));
echo "</pre>";
```

---

Comment: Edit the comment again. I downvoted by mistake and only noticed it when I could not revert it. I get: "You last voted on this answer 1 hour ago. Your vote is now locked in unless this answer is edited." Anyway, I did not understand the requisites, since the implementations give different results.

Comment: Yes it gives different results because I want every combinations to be unique. With this function, I can get every possible algorithms.

Answer (score 0):

You can simplify this logic (and make the code less ugly) without needing to go recursive by using:

```
for ($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++) {
    $subset[] = $numbers[$i];
    for ($j=$i; $j < $count; $j++) {
        $subset[] = $numbers[$i] . $numbers[$j];
        for ($k=$j; $k < $count; $k++) {
            $subset[] = $numbers[$i] . $numbers[$j] . $numbers[$k];
            for ($l=$k; $l < $count; $l++) {
                $subset[] = $numbers[$i] . $numbers[$j] . $numbers[$k] . $numbers[$l];
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes you are true but what if I need 8 item combination? Every time I will need to copy it and add extra loops

Answer (score 0):

the following will work in all cases even if you have duplicate numbers in your array

```
$array = array(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14);  
 sort($array);  //in case it 's not sorted
 $array = array_slice($array,-7);   
 $num = count($array );  
  $total = pow(2, $num);
  $result= array();
  $element='';
   for ($i = 0; $i < $total; $i++) 
    {      

          for ($j = 0; $j < $num; $j++) 
              {                 
                 if (pow(2, $j) & $i) 
                 {
                 $element=$element.$array [$j];                 
                 }                                       
              }
              $result[]=$element;
              $element=''; 
      }
      print_r($result);
```

Comment: But the numbers array can be and usually more then 7 numbers. How can I rescrict to have the maximum 7 of numbers combined?

Comment: You need the combinations of the  greater seven numbers in the array? Sorry i don't understand.

Comment: No. Let's say I have a number array like this on some situations `$array = array(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14);` But each combination must use maximum 7 of these numbers.

Comment: Now it does not return all possibilities, though. It simply excludes the first 7 values altogether.

Answer (score 0):

This implementation returns all the combinations of all items (7<sup>7</sup> = 823542 combinations of 7 items):

```
function combine_all(array $numbers) {
    $count = count($numbers);

    $result = array_map('strval', $numbers);
    for($i = 1; $i < $count; ++$i) {
        $combinations = array_slice($result, pow($count, $i-1));
        foreach($numbers as $number) {
            foreach($combinations as $combination) {
                $result[] = $number . ',' . $combination;
            }
        }
    }

    return $result;
}
```

When using print_r to output the data, it can perform very slowly:

```
$array = array_fill(0, pow(7,7), '');
$t = microtime(true);
echo '<pre>';
print_r($array);
echo '</pre>';
echo microtime(true) - $t;
// 0.75329303741455


$t = microtime(true);
echo '<pre>';
print_r( combine_all(array(1,2,3,4,5,6,7)) );
echo '</pre>';
echo microtime(true) - $t;
// 1.7037351131439


$t = microtime(true);
combine_all(array(1,2,3,4,5,6,7));
echo microtime(true) - $t;
//0.75869607925415
```

To restrict the items number, use the [array_slice](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-slice.php) function:

```
combine_all(array_slice($numbers, 0, 7));
```

If you really want a recursive function, you could do something like this:

```
function combine_all(array $numbers, $cnt=null, $baseCombination=null) {
    if( $baseCombination === null ) {
        $cnt = count($numbers);
    }

    if( $cnt > 0 ) {
        $result = array();
        foreach($numbers as $number) {
            $combination = $number . ',' . $baseCombination;
            $result[] = $combination;
            $result = array_merge($result, combine_all($numbers, $cnt-1, $combination));
        }
        return $result;
    }

    return array();
}
```

But [it takes too much memory](http://www2.hawaii.edu/~tp_200/lectureNotes/recursion.htm).